# Git only kept my java files and deleted the rest

Tags: git, github

It was my first time using git and I wanted to add a project to github, I used the following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Commit 1"
git remote add origin <my url>
git push origin master
```

As soon as I did this I noticed git deleted all my local files that were in that folder and the only files I got in my repository were java files, so all the rest was deleted.

Any way to revert back the damage?

Comment: Did you notice at which step they disappeared? (none of these commands should delete files). Next time use revision control from the start, and build up slowly.

Comment: Do you mean that only java files appear online, but locally you still have additional files? This would sound like files being excluded in a `.gitignore` file.